# How to impose restrictions on predictions made using a Bayesian structural time series model as implemented in the R package CausalImpact?

Tags: r

The [CausalImpact](https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html) R package from Google provides a user-friendly interface to a [Bayesian structural time series modeling](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub41854.html) approach, which allows one to obtain counterfactual predictions and estimate causal impacts (e.g., efficiency of an ad campaign) in the absence of a real control group. The problem I am facing when using this software is that in some cases, when the modeled response is a count variable, the prediction intervals and/or predicted mean values may take on negative values, which is obviously implausible for such variables.

One straightforward work-around would be to use log-transformed values of the response and then transform the results back onto the original scale (in fact, [this approach has already been mentioned](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/causalimpact/5zwq__yulVE) by the package's author). Transforming back any summary statistics produced by CausalImpact, however, is not exactly helpful when it comes to interpretation of the results on the original scale. Here is what I mean - consider the following example:

```
y = c(7, 18, 11, 3, 3, 2, 89, 94, 48, 74,
      21, 13, 5, 9, 10, 18, 12, 4, 8, 4, 12, 8, 6, 7, 6)
x = c(7, 22, 28, 13, 16, 6, 4, 2, 2, 24, 8,
      9, 5, 5, 8, 7, 5, 11, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 2, 6)

dat = as.ts(cbind(y, x))
pre.period <- c(1, 6)
post.period <- c(7, 25)

library(CausalImpact)
impact <- CausalImpact(dat, pre.period, post.period)
plot(impact)
```

[image: impact]

```
summary(impact)
Posterior inference {CausalImpact}

                         Average        Cumulative     
Actual                   24             448            
Prediction (s.d.)        2.9 (2.1)      54.8 (39.1)    
95% CI                   [-0.98, 6.8]   [-18.69, 129.1]

Absolute effect (s.d.)   21 (2.1)       393 (39.1)     
95% CI                   [17, 25]       [319, 467]     

Relative effect (s.d.)   718% (71%)     718% (71%)     
95% CI                   [582%, 852%]   [582%, 852%]   

Posterior tail-area probability p:   0.00111
Posterior prob. of a causal effect:  99.88901%

For more details, type: summary(impact, "report")
```

As is seen from the above plot and the summary table, the 95% credible intervals of the Actual include negative values. The absolute effect of the intervention was 21, cumulative - 393, and relative - 718%.

Now, let's re-run the same model on a log-transformed response:

```
ylog = log(y)
dat2 = as.ts(cbind(ylog, x))
impactLog <- CausalImpact(dat2, pre.period, post.period)
plot(impactLog)
```

[image: impactLog]

```
summary(impactLog)
Posterior inference {CausalImpact}

                         Average       Cumulative   
Actual                   2.6           49.2         
Prediction (s.d.)        1.1 (0.28)    20.1 (5.29)  
95% CI                   [0.54, 1.6]   [10.17, 30.3]

Absolute effect (s.d.)   1.5 (0.28)    29.2 (5.29)  
95% CI                   [1, 2.1]      [19, 39.1]   

Relative effect (s.d.)   145% (26%)    145% (26%)   
95% CI                   [94%, 194%]   [94%, 194%]  

Posterior tail-area probability p:   0.00111
Posterior prob. of a causal effect:  99.88901%

For more details, type: summary(impact, "report")
```

Of course, trying to interpret the antilog-transformed impact-related summary statistics from the above table would not make sense on the original additive scale. For example, the absolute effect becomes exp(1.5) = 4.48, the cumulative effect becomes exp(49.2) = 2.33e+21, etc. The antilog transformation has to take place on the raw values used to construct the above summary statistics, but *I don't seem to figure out where those raw values are sitting and how to calculate meaningful summary stats on the original scale*. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure. However, both x and y are skewed. To run time series analysis, they should be log-transformed first.

Answer (score 0):

For the effect, you can antilog transform `response` and `point.pred` and then subtract to get the effects:

Your original, non-log results:

(average, cumulative)

```
> impact$summary$AbsEffect
[1]  20.60043 391.40809
```

To get the average effects using log transformed data:

```
> mean(exp(impactLog$series$response[7:25,]) - exp(impactLog$series$point.pred[7:25,]))
[1] 20.44092
```

...and the cumulative effect:

```
> sum(exp(impactLog$series$response[7:25,]) - exp(impactLog$series$point.pred[7:25,]))
[1] 388.3774
```

(The small difference between the two results is due to the randomness in the MCMC process.)

If you want the point-wise effects, it's the same as above but without `mean` or `sum`.

For the credible interval for the absolute average effect:

```
> # lower
> mean(exp(impactLog$series$response[7:25,]) - exp(impactLog$series$point.pred.upper[7:25,]))
[1] 15.22143

> # upper
> mean(exp(impactLog$series$response[7:25,]) - exp(impactLog$series$point.pred.lower[7:25,]))
[1] 22.40529
```

For the cumulative credible interval, replace `mean` with `sum`.

Answer (score -1):

For interpreting the results, have you tried? summary(impact, "report")
It generally tells you

"During the post-intervention period, the response variable had an average value of approx. 24. By contrast, in the absence of an intervention, we would have expected an average response of 3. The 95% interval of this counterfactual prediction is [-1, 7]. Subtracting this prediction from the observed response yields an estimate of the causal effect the intervention had on the response variable. This effect is 21 with a 95% interval of [17, 25]. For a discussion of the significance of this effect, see below.

Summing up the individual data points during the post-intervention period (which can only sometimes be meaningfully interpreted), the response variable had an overall value of 448. By contrast, had the intervention not taken place, we would have expected a sum of 55. The 95% interval of this prediction is [-18, 128].

The above results are given in terms of absolute numbers. In relative terms, the response variable showed an increase of +718%. The 95% interval of this percentage is [+585%, +850%].

This means that the positive effect observed during the intervention period is statistically significant and unlikely to be due to random fluctuations. It should be noted, however, that the question of whether this increase also bears substantive significance can only be answered by comparing the absolute effect (21) to the original goal of the underlying intervention.

The probability of obtaining this effect by chance is very small (Bayesian tail-area probability p = 0.001). This means the causal effect can be considered statistically significant. "